# c++ hello world throws Segmentation fault - MinGW, Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, segmentation-fault, mingw

Set up MinGW and Netbeans. Only working withe othere IDE's and compilers in before. My machine is x64 win7x64. I'm not shure if I only installed the 32bit version of MinGW.

Compiling a simpel Helle World in x64 leeds to:

```
g++ -m64   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" 
    -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
//Message: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in

The win32 Version compiles fine.
// ---
g++ -m32   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
    -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
// Compiles without any error...
```

Starting the 32-Version it prints only one message and terminats withe a segmentation fault before returning from first std:cout. Using ftream, to make a file output same error occures.
The demo-Programm of netbeans "Welcome" throws the same exceptions.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>   // EDIT! (worked at this post long time sry.)
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int i = 0; // for making shure, program is working before calling fs.open
std::cout << "hello world blubb" << endl;   // this one shows up its message at consol.
//programm aborded.
std::cout << "Now again" << endl;   // this on is never reached.
return 0;
}
```

Errormessages:

```
Signal received: SIGSEGV ( Segmentation fault )
For programm cppapplication_1 pid 7972

You may discard...
```

Errormessage windows:

```
cppapplication_1.exe does not work.
```

*Where can I start my serach? Compiler? some dlls? Dependency Walker?*

Thx for any comment =).
Cutton

Comment: You will need the <iostream> header for using cout.

Comment: your're right, I post a wrong code line, while editing this question. once and once again.